# Is it possible to delete an ArrayList reference?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a class that contains an ArrayList. I would like to know if it's possible to delete it's reference entirely, not only its objects.

The class is as follows:

```
public class Process {
    private int id;
    private int arrivalTime;
    private int CpuTime;
    private int timeSlice;
    private int processTime;
    private boolean blocked;
    private boolean running;
    private ArrayList<IO> IoArray = new ArrayList<IO>();
}
```

I'd like to remove any references to IoArray

Comment: Set `IoArray` to `null`.

Comment: You can assign `null` to it. Otherwise, I don't know what you mean.

Comment: do you mean make it so process.IoArray is no longer a thing (not even null). If so no, java is a statically typed language where that sort of horror isn't possible

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant Richard. Thanks for the clarification, I am guessing my question wasn't clear enough.

Comment: you can create the sort of "dynamic variable" using a hashmap which connects a key to a value. But only use them when appropriate. By and large static typing is awesome. If we knew what your use case was we could better advise

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just set

```
process.IoArray = null;
```

or

```
process.IoArray = collections.emptyList();
```

Although I'm not sure why you would need to do this.